# How to define a vector that its elements are created in a For Loop?

Tags: matlab, vector, symbolic-math

I want to define a vector,X, with five elements:

```
syms a
X = zeros(1,5)
X(1) = 1;
for k=1:4
    X(k+1)=X(k)+a^2;
end
```

Actually I need to have the vector X, that its elements should be based on variable a. But I face an error in Matlab, when I write the code above:

```
The following error occurred converting from sym to double:
Error using symengine (line 58)
DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.
If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use VPA.

Error in Code2 (line 5)
X(k+1)=X(k)*a^2;
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Remove `syms a` and give `a` a value? Why are you using symbolic math here?

Comment: @beaker , the elements of vector 'X' will be the coefficients of a polynomial: 'x(t,a) = X(1)+X(2)t+X(3)t^2+...', So the result should be a function 'x(a,t)' of 'a' and 't'. And then I have to calculate partial derivative of 'x(t,a)' with respect to 'a'. Therefore I cannot simply put a value instead of 'a'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing between symbolic variables to doubles,
Doubles holds a value, you can use the loop that you wrote only if a is a double and already holds a value (the value can be the input of a function) .
for example :

```
function ret=testFunc(a)
X = zeros(1,5)
X(1) = 1;
for k=1:4
    X(k+1)=X(k)+a^2;
end
ret=X
end
```

if you want to work with syms (for other symbolic analysis) you can define x as a symbol too, for example :

```
syms a x
x(1)=1;
for i=2:5
x(i)=x(i-1)+a.^2;
end
```

now, x is a function of a, and if you print x you will get :

```
[ 1, a^2 + 1, 2*a^2 + 1, 3*a^2 + 1, 4*a^2 + 1]
```

to evaluate the value of x, you will still need to input a value for a.

Matlab help suggest subs function for replacing a in wanted value as follows:

```
y = subs(x,a,4)
```

in that point y is still a symbol and you will need to make it a double by using

```
double(y)
```